# Filter latest reply from php imap

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm using the PHP imap lib. I have no problems pulling e-mails and reading the plain body. ($mail->textPlain). However this takes the entire body (including the conversation/history). I want to filter the history and only keep the reply. I tried using regex and that works fine for Gmail but for other email clients it doens't work. Does someone knows a workaround or a library?

```
preg_replace('#(^\w.+:\n)?(^>.*(\n|$))+#mi', "", $mail->textPlain);
```

I'm aware that php imap does not provide a method for that but I'm want to know if there are libraries for it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Alright, well I tried to use preg_replace to filter out the old conversation but that does only work for Gmail. For example in Outlook client it doesn't work because the format is different. I would like to know how to cover more mail clients.